# How to get page total count of page likes in facebook api v2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes

total_count property: Total number of people who liked. This is only returned when the flag summary=true is set.

I am wondering where to set summary=true

I am using FB node module

Following is my code snippet

```
FB.api('xxxxx', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'likes', 'checkins', 'talking_about_count'],
    access_token: accessToken
}, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `fan_count` field of the `Page` object.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading